# Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I use spring-jpa with hibernate implementation. I use mariadb and  I try to do an update subquery

My object structure

```
@Entity
public class Room {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long roomId;

  @ManyToOne  
  @JoinColumn(name = "appartment_id")
  private Appartment appartment;
}

@Entity
public class Appartment {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long appartmentId;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="appartment_id")
  private Set<Room> roomList;
}

update Room r1
set r1.available = :availability
where r1.roomId in
( select r2.roomId from Room r2 JOIN r2.appartment a1 WHERE a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId )
```

I get this error

java.sql.SQLException: Table 'room' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Answer (score 5):

This is a restriction in MySQL:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

*You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.*

There is a fudge you can do *sometimes* do to hide the sub query in a a further level of sub query that might work. Something like this (not tested):-

```
UPDATE Room r1
SET r1.available = :availability
WHERE r1.roomId IN
    SELECT roomId
    FROM
    ( 
        SELECT r2.roomId 
        FROM Room r2 
        JOIN r2.appartment a1 
        WHERE a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId 
    )
```

Note that your query possibly has an error. In the sub query you are joining the table Room aliased as r2 to a table called appartment on a database called r2. Also your sub query does a JOIN without a join condition.

However you can quite possibly just do the join in the UPDATE statement without the need for a sub query:-

```
UPDATE Room 
INNER JOIN r2.appartment a1
ON Room.roomId = a1.roomId
SET r1.available = :availability
WHERE a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId
```

Comment: jpa don't like both.

Comment: In which case looks like you are suffering from using a restrictive framework that stops you using the facilities the database offers.

Comment: @Kickstart How can we use LIMIT in UPDATE  joining query?

Comment: @hmjha - Depends on the query. On a simple UPDATE you can use ORDER BY / LIMIT easily. I think with multiple tables you would need to use a SELECT with a LIMIT in a sub query and then join against that subquery for the actual UPDATE.

Comment: @roberttrudel - try my answer, tested with hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

A solution will be to select `roomIds` seperatly and pass them as a parameter.

**Select id list**

```
List<Long> roomIdList = entityManager.createQuery(
                    """SELECT r2.roomId 
                    FROM Room r2 
                    JOIN r2.appartment a1 
                    WHERE a1.appartmentId = :appartmentId""", Long.class)
                    .setParameter("appartmentId", appartmentId)
                    .getResultList();
```

**Pass it as a parameter**

```
int updated = entityManager.createQuery(
                    """UPDATE Room r1
                    SET r1.available = :availability
                    WHERE r1.roomId IN :roomIds""")
                    .setParameter("availability", availability)
                    .setParameter("roomIds", roomIdList)
                    .executeUpdate();
```