# Add SELECT to UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, database

Trying to get a query to work. I have an email address as a variable and need to update all rows in this ranking that are above the matching record. The query:

```
UPDATE quiz_1_highscore 
    SET rate = rate - 1 
WHERE rate >= ( SELECT rate FROM quiz_1_highscore WHERE email = ? )
```

Then I bind the parameter for the email from a form submit, but the query does not work.

I don't want to make two calls to the database - one to get the rate in that email row, and a second one to perform the update. Can I do it all in one query?

**EDIT:**

Just trying to add Caius comment:

```
UPDATE quiz_1_highscore AS T1 SET T1.rate = T1.rate - 1 WHERE T1.rate >= ( SELECT MAX(T2.rate) FROM quiz_1_highscore AS T2 WHERE T2.email = ? );
```

This work if I run it in "mysql workbrench" - but in my php files I get that error -

```
ErrorSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 Table 'T1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

PLEASE HELP :\

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: *but this query isn't working*: How is it not working? Do you get an error message, what is it?  And where are you running the SQL from?  This doesn't seem like just a SQL question.

Comment: Is only one record should be with email or multiple?

Comment: Sorry, please clarify the following : " that are above the matching record."  the concept of "above" is meaningless without context within a database.

Comment: PDO || Look at Caius answer comments to see the error || Yes only one record have email it should bring in for example 5 then all record that greater than 5 should be update (decrease by one)

Answer (score 0):

The nested SELECT statement is a table, not a value. Use

```
( SELECT MAX(rate) FROM quiz_1_highscore WHERE email = ? )
```

or some other aggregation function.

```
UPDATE quiz_1_highscore AS T1 SET T1.rate = T1.rate - 1 WHERE T1.rate >= ( SELECT MAX(T2.rate) FROM quiz_1_highscore AS T2 WHERE T2.email = ? );
```

Comment: Hey, It's working on workbench but in the php file it get me exception: ErrorSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 Table 'quiz_1_highscore' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: don't work eigther - ErrorSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'pokerquiz.mytable' doesn't exist

Comment: Can I see the whole query

Comment: UPDATE quiz_1_highscore AS mytable SET rate = rate - 1 WHERE `rate` >= ( SELECT MAX(`rate`) FROM mytable WHERE `email` = ? );

Comment: You're not actually using the aliases here. Every time you mention a column you should call it `alias`.`column` instead of `column`. More importantly though, you need to give the table in the nested statement its own alias, separate from the outer one. See my edit above.

Comment: It's still give me the error of twice table use... just now it says T1 instead of  quiz_1_highscore --- "ErrorSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 Table 'T1' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data"

Comment: As I said before, you need to use TWO separate aliases for your table. Please refer to my edited response above.

Comment: Oh you're using mysql, which apparently doesn't allow updating and selecting the same table in the same query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486177/table-is-specified-twice-both-as-a-target-for-update-and-as-a-separate-source You may just need to separate it into two queries after all.

Comment: :\ - I can't make a variable for the SELECT then put it in the UPDATE in same query or something? I don't want to make 2 db calls...

Answer (score 0):

Probably sub-query you should limit to one row adding: LIMIT 1