# Delete identical row in many MySQL tables

Tags: django

I'm looking for delete some identical rows present in 4 databases.
Each database has a table named `Identity_Individu`. Don't worry about this process, it's the only way found in order to share data between databases because Data Cross Relation are not allowed with Django.

I have this part :

```
#settings.py file
BDD = ('default', 'DS_Douane', 'DS_Impots', 'DS_Finance')

#views.py file

@login_required
def Identity_Deleting(request) :

    query_number = request.GET.get('q6')

    if query_number :
        query_number_list = Individu.objects.filter(NumeroIdentification__iexact=query_number)    
    else :
        query_number_list = Individu.objects.none()

    form = IndividuFormulaire(request.POST or None, instance = query_number_list.first())

    if "Delete" in request.POST :
        for element in settings.BDD :
            form = Individu.objects.filter(pk=query_number_list).delete().using(element)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Home'))
```

I'm getting an issue :

> (1093, "Table 'Identity_individu' is specified twice, both as a target
>   for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data")

How I have to use `.delete()` with `using()` in order to delete all rows respecting the condition in each table ?

I tried `.delete(using=element)` but I got :

> delete() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'

Comment: I am not sure, but does it make a difference to do the using first ?  Individu.objects.using(element).filter(pk=query_number_list).delete()

Comment: @Thom Nope, I still get the same issue : `(1093, "Table 'Identity_individu' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data")` :/ All django documentations say : `.delete(using=...)` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I tried it on my side and it works (no matter where the .using() is place), seems like there is a constraint on mysql. Maybe try to see with Django Debug Toolbar what SQL query is executed.

Comment: I have different database ^^ Did you try with different one on the same time ?

Comment: Yes I tried with 2 SQLite DB :)

Comment: I'm using MariaDB, so we don't have the same working environment. With Django Debug, this is the SQL command : `DELETE FROM 'Identity_individu' WHERE 'Identity_individu'.'id' = (SELECT U0.'id' FROM 'Identity_individu' U0 WHERE U0.'NumeroIdentification' LIKE '11111L-999244')'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147702/discussion-between-thom-and-deadpool).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution after we [talked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147702/discussion-between-thom-and-deadpool) :)

```
@login_required
def Identity_Deleting(request) :

    query_number = request.GET.get('q6')

    if query_number :
        query_number_list = Individu.objects.filter(NumeroIdentification__iexact=query_number)    
    else :
        query_number_list = Individu.objects.none()

    instance = query_number_list.first()
    form = IndividuFormulaire(request.POST or None, instance = query_number_list.first())

    if "Delete" in request.POST :
        ids_to_delete = list(query_number_list.values_list('id', flat=True))
        for element in settings.BDD :
            form = Individu.objects.using(element).filter(pk__in=ids_to_delete).delete() 

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Home'))
```

There is two importants things:

- The first queryset `query_number_list` result should be saved in a `list` in order to be used later
- `.using()` should be used before `.delete()`

Answer (score 1):

It is a mysql restriction, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35504972/4797469).

Try to modify your request by forcing evaluation of queryset instead of using a subquery using `list`:

```
 Individu.objects.filter(pk__in=list(query_number_list.values_list('id', flat=True))).delete().using(element)
```

or if there is always only 1 `Individu` you may want something like:

```
@login_required
def Identity_Deleting(request) :

    query_number = request.GET.get('q6')

    if query_number :
        individu = Individu.objects.filter(NumeroIdentification__iexact=query_number).first()
    else :
        individu = None

    form = IndividuFormulaire(request.POST or None, instance = individu)

    if "Delete" in request.POST:
        if individu is not None:
            for element in settings.BDD :
                Individu.objects.filter(pk=individu.pk).delete().using(element)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Home'))
```

Comment: I tried your answer and I got : `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`. It doesn't should be a list, because I'm looping over each database to delete the row.

Comment: have you tried pk__in instead of pk  as I suggested ? Looking again at your code, you could just use `first()`: I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried and always the same issu : `(1093, "Table 'Identity_individu' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data")`

Comment: Your answer has removed `individu` in default database, but not in others. I have to see why ;)

Comment: Do they have same pk in all DBs? or you may want to delete base on NumeroIdentification... Bonne chance ;)

Comment: Yes same PK ;) I have to see in details why it doesn't work ;) Thanks